# cannot select any menu in backend - site is always loading

Tags: magento2

I can login into my backend but when I try to select any menu in backend nothing will happen.
I notice that when I login in backend the website is always loading.

Here the errors of the console:
[image]
Hope someone can help me how I can solve this.
kindly regards for any answer.

Comment: Can you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the backend I cannot see any error. How can I check the errors in the console? (which console do you mean?)
kindly regards

Comment: I add the errors of the console in my question.

Comment: 0

I am experiencing a similar issue. Updated from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4. When logging into Magento Backend no submenus at the left panel or (for example) drop-downs for Store view appears. To get the drop-down menus to appear, I can CTRL F5 and this will bring them back, but only temporarily. Within a few minutes, it returns to nothing happening when trying access the drop-downs on the left side

Comment: Hi! 
I have changed back my settings of an extension in the database which I have done before.
Now all is still working.
Kindly regards